# Eclipse: Files not showing in project explorer

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-indigo

There's a certain project I'm trying to open on Eclipse. But when I browse for the project's location and choose it, it loads and then gives me an empty project explorer. Why?

I don't know if this is relevant, but the project I'm trying to open has been created on a different machine than mine. And I'm mentioning that, because when I try to open a project that I created on my machine, all the files show in the project explorer and I face no trouble.

So what could be the reason behind that? And how can I solve it? Should I import the files rather than opening the whole path as a workbench?

Comment: Does navigator display anything?

Comment: @ChetterHummin nope, it's empty too

Comment: did u do import existing project?

Comment: @NaveenBabu yes, I tried to do so, but it gave me an error: Invalid project description.
and in the details for the error it says that the project i'm trying to import overlaps the workspace I'm trying to import in the first place

Comment: can you copy the full workspace into your machine and try to load that workspace when eclipse starts. Most probably you would have created a new project and some how replaced it.

Comment: @NaveenBabu it is already on my machine. and i have been trying to load it the same way you just mentioned

Comment: did u happen to have some extra plugin in the old pc? since u mentioned of having a invalid project description error.

Comment: @NaveenBabu it all worked out.. thank you

Comment: what was the issue? if it is strange issue, post it here so others could use the solution

Comment: @NaveenBabu I think the issues was with the plugin as you mentioned. I solved it in a very beginner kind of way; I just created a new project and copy-pasted the src files